# Is the complement of open sets the whole set in this proof?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-explanation, set-theory, solution-verification

I am going over [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1100730/517255) and for the most part it makes sense to me. However, towards the end it says

"
Let's see that $p(X\setminus V)\cup p(X\setminus U)=Y$. If $y\in Y$, then $y=f(x)$ for some $x\in X$. Since $U\cap V=\emptyset$, we have either $x\in X\setminus U$ or $x\in X\setminus V$; so the thesis follows.

Therefore $U_1\cap V_1=\emptyset$."

Why either $x \in X \setminus V$ or $x\in X\setminus U$? Can't we have, possibly, $x\notin X\setminus V$ and $x \notin X\setminus U$? I understand $y=f(x)$ for some $x\in X$, since $f$ is surjective. Also isn't the statement  $x \in X \setminus V$ or $x\in X\setminus U$ implying $(X\setminus U) \cup(X\setminus V)=X$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x\notin X\setminus V$, then $x\in V$. Similarly, if $x\notin X\setminus U$, then $x\in U$. Thus, if $x\notin X\setminus V$ **and** $x\notin X\setminus U$, then $x\in V$ and $x\in U$, i.e., $x\in U\cap V$. But $U\cap V=\varnothing$, so this is impossible.

More generally, if $X$ is any set, and $A$ and $B$ are disjoint subsets of $X$, then $(X\setminus A)\cup(X\setminus B)=X$. You can prove this by the argument that I used above, or you can use De Morgan’s laws:

$$\begin{align*}
(X\setminus A)\cup(X\setminus B)&=X\setminus(A\cap B)\\
&=X\setminus\varnothing\\
&=X\,.
\end{align*}$$